# how to fputcsv of associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key, associative-array

I have an associative multidimesional array and i'm trying to fputcsv all the fields but in the last two key ("foto_thumb","foto_large") i have n.index and fputcsv print "array" and gives me back an error (this happens because in ["foto_thumb"],["foto_large"] i have another dimension with n. index == numero_foto)

this is the code i'm using:

```
for( $i=0; $i < 2; $i++ ){


$array_key[$i]["titolo"] = $data[$i]['listing']['title'];
$array_key[$i]["prezzo"] = $data[$i]['listing']['price']['formattedPrice'][0];
$array_key[$i]["descrizione"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['description'];
$array_key[$i]["condizioni"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['condition']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["costituzione"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['surfaceConstitution']['surfaceConstitutionElements'][0]['constitution'];
$array_key[$i]["piano"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['surfaceConstitution']['surfaceConstitutionElements'][0]['floor'];
$array_key[$i]["superficie"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['surfaceConstitution']['surfaceConstitutionElements'][0]['surface'];
$array_key[$i]["tipo"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['typology']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["categoria"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['category']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["foto planimetria thumb"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['floorplans'][0]['urls']['thumb'];
$array_key[$i]["foto planimetria large"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['floorplans'][0]['urls']['large'];
$array_key[$i]["latitudine"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['latitude'];
$array_key[$i]["longitudine"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['longitude'];
$array_key[$i]["nazione"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['nation']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["regione"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['region']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["provincia"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['province']['name'];  
$array_key[$i]["città"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['city']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["macrozona"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['macrozone']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["microzona"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['microzone']['name'];
$array_key[$i]["indirizzo"] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['address']." ".$data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['location']['streetNumber'];

    for( $j=0; $j < $numero_foto[$i]; $j++ ){
   
    $array_key[$i]["foto_thumb"][] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['photos'][$j]['urls']['thumb'];
    $array_key[$i]["foto_large"][] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['photos'][$j]['urls']['large'];
    }
}

print_r($array_key);
//inserisco nell'array tutte le foto

foreach(array_keys($array_key[0])as $key){
    $headers[] = $key;
}

print_r($headers);

$file = fopen("data.csv","w");

fputcsv($file, $headers);

foreach($array_key as $fields){
    fputcsv($file, $fields);
 }

print_r($fields);
fclose($file);
```

my output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqZyl.png)

i want all the photos url instead of Array...

Answer (score 0):

Make the array into a string using json_decode, after the inner loop that creates it.

```
for( $j=0; $j < $numero_foto[$i]; $j++ ){
    $array_key[$i]["foto_thumb"][] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['photos'][$j]['urls']['thumb'];
    $array_key[$i]["foto_large"][] = $data[$i]['listing']['properties'][0]['multimedia']['photos'][$j]['urls']['large'];
}

// add this:
$array_key[$i]["foto_thumb"] = json_encode($array_key[$i]["foto_thumb"]);
$array_key[$i]["foto_large"] = json_encode($array_key[$i]["foto_large"]);
```